# Another term for "Extreme words"?

Tags: expressions

Words like "totally", "completely", "all", "entirely, "no" etc. These group of words point to the extremes. Do we have a term for these group of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term for these words is "*absolute adverbs*". This page from [education.com](http://www.education.com/study-help/article/adverbs1/) contains the following explanation:

> Absolute adverbs—words like all, every, completely, and
>   entirely—already refer to everything possible, and therefore cannot be
>   intensified any further.

Answer (score 0):

[su·per·la·tive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/superlative)  (s-pûrl-tv)
adj.

> 1. Of the highest order, quality, or degree; surpassing or superior to all others.
> 2. Excessive or exaggerated.
> 3. Grammar Of, relating to, or being the extreme degree of comparison of an adjective or adverb, as in best or brightest.
>      n.
> 4. Something of the highest possible excellence.
> 5. The highest degree; the acme.
> 6. Grammar
>
>    - a. The superlative degree.
>    - b. An adjective or adverb expressing the superlative degree, as in brightest, the -superlative of the adjective bright, or most brightly, the superlative of the adverb brightly.

Comment: A superlative has a subtle difference from absolute adverbs. However, this is still useful.

Comment: If saying "She is so totally wrong" is absolute, what would be "She is so totally totally completely wrong"?

Comment: @BlessedGeek: redundant.

Comment: Would both phrases express the same level of intensity? The answer should be "yes", if one of them has redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Does the word *intensifiers* aptly describe these words? That's my answer by the way

Comment: First, this is a very short answer. Here are normally encouraged longer answers which give not just the "answer" but also an explanation and provide references to additional material. Secondly,  this isn't even a complete answer, because you have said the OP can use "intensifiers" but haven't explained why?

Comment: You should provide some references and be sure about your answer.

Comment: Advice heeded. Will be more proper next time.

Answer (score 0):

The words are signal words for the signpost, Extreme Language or Absolute Language.

Comment: Hi @Kat, Please cite appropriate references which back up your answer. Also, briefly defining the Extreme/Absolute Language concepts will improve the quality of your response.